# How to display user accounts picture and name inside a box from database in html page using php and mysqli?

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I want to display all the user account photo and name from database and put one user photo and name in a div tag and similarly with all the accounts with a link that redirect to the clicked account. But I am having problem on how to display it.If its still not clear try picturing an online shopping site where each product with its name is in its own box separately. Please help, I am actually trying to make a social networking site for my educational project. Thank You.
Heres my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE NOT username = '$username'";
$account = array();
$photo1 = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $account[] = $row['username'];
        $a = $row['photo'];
        $photo1[] = "<img src = '$a' alt = 'profile photo' width = '100px' height = '100px'>";
    }
}

and Heres a section of my html code: 
<div>
    <?php echo implode(', ',$photo1); ?>    
    <?php echo implode(', ',$account);?>
</div>
```

[This is the image that I uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vfwh.png)

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Comment: How are you storing the image?
What do you see when you run this?

Comment: the code is working, the thing is all the name is displaying after all the image is displayed. What I want is the name should appear below the image and those two content only should be inside a box, and right now I cant seem to display it like I want using an array

Comment: @JGreatorex, can you please check the image I uploaded below the code, I am storing the image by inserting the location of the image in a database...

Comment: So, if I understand that correctly, your markup is not generated in the way you would expect it? What keeps you from changing it?

Comment: the code inside the div tag. that code works by displaying all the images right next to each other, i cant separate them by trying to put the 2nd line php code(inside <div>) between each image or below the image(below or between both will help)

Answer (score 0):

Could you add some wireframe for your task?

In this way i think you need something like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="$linkToUserProfile"><img src="$imgSource" alt="" title=""></a>
    <a href="$linkToUserProfile">$userName</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That helps, but I'm not sure that will display all the records. It will display only one image as theres only one img tag and all the other name if im not wrong

Comment: Can you explain what that kind of "wireframe" is and why that is needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
#try this and then add html as you need
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM user  ";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
          echo $row['username'];
          $a = 'www.yourdomain.com/usriamegefolder/'.$row['photo'];
          echo "<img src = '$a' alt = 'profile photo' width = '100px' height = '100px'>";
        }
     }
```

Comment: i don't understand why another url is stored in the $a variable because i already  fetch the url by $row['photo'] (i believe that's the same).